# Eclipse plugin for weblogic standalone

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, weblogic11g, oc4j

Are there any standalone plugin available for Oracle Weblogic 11g for eclipse?
Something very similar to Jdeveloper web applications using embedded OC4J?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you need?

http://dietrichschroff.blogspot.com/2009/07/using-eclipse-with-oracle-application.html

[Oracle Enterprise Pack for Eclipse 11gR1 (11.1.1.8)](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/eclipse/downloads/oepe-11118-521475.html)

Comment: Thanks for the update. I installed Oracle Enterprise Pack for Eclipse. Do I need to have Weblogic Standalone Server to be installed? Because while creating New Server in Eclipse, it is asking for Weblogic home. Or Oracle Enterprise Pack has an embedded weblogic server?

Comment: Dave I guess my above comment is not necessary, I guess I found the solution. Thanks